# LSTM Time Series Prediction Issue: Predictions Shifted Relative to Actuals

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, forecasting

I followed a tutorial on youtube on how to forecast time series using LSTM, I used it on my NDVI dataset, the problem is that the predictions are consistently shifted by one time step compared to the actual values. I want to know, if this is normal (so I should shift it back by one step) or there is a problem with the model I used? [image: Example]

This is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'NDVI.csv')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date time'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
NDVI = df['NDVI']

def df_to_X_y(df, window_size=3):
    df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
        row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+3]]
        X.append(row)
        label = df_as_np[i+3]
        y.append(label)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

WINDOW_SIZE=3
X,y= df_to_X_y(NDVI, WINDOW_SIZE)
X.shape, y.shape

X_train, y_train = X[:410], y[:410]
X_val, y_val= X[410:456], y[410:456]
X_test, y_test = X[456:], y[456:]
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint# for Saving models
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(InputLayer((3, 1)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))

model1.summary()

cp = ModelCheckpoint('NDVImodel/', save_best_only=True)

model1.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])
model1.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=20, callbacks=[cp])
train_predictions = model1.predict(X_train).flatten()
train_results=pd.DataFrame(data={'Train Predictions': train_predictions, 'Actuals':y_train})

val_predictions = model1.predict(X_val).flatten()
val_results = pd.DataFrame(data={'Val Predictions':val_predictions, 'Actuals':y_val})
val_results
plt.plot(val_results['Val Predictions'])
plt.plot(val_results['Actuals'])  #the results of this are what displayed in the image
```